# Automatically Increase and Decrease Window Size

Tags: window

How do I automatically increase the size of the window when I switch into it and reduce it back to its normal size when I switch out of it?

I have a small window at the bottom of my screen. While editing a buffer in this window, I want to see it in a larger size and once I switch into a different window I want the bottom buffer return back to its original size.

Comment: I believe the `zoom` package on melpa is your friend.  It does exactly that.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion. It is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: There is an golden-ratio mode. It does what exactly you want! maybe you will like it.